# How do i build a grid like the one on azure dashboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am building a kind of dashboard for my web application. And i need something like a grid to allow the user to create the layout of the "widgets". I kind og like the way that azure does it:[image]

What i am after is a way to arrange and resize my components by letting them snap to the grid. And at the same time allow them to be moved around. I started out by using the JQueryUI for drag and drop, but i just cant seem to get the grid lines working properly and then the placement. Furthermore i need a kind of object in my Javascript that i can serialize to json or xml to post it to my server.

Should i build this myself, or are there JS frameworks for this. Can this be done in plain jquery/jqueryUI and how do i draw the background?

Comment: Question is off topic for several reasons, too broad and asking for resource recommendations

Comment: Potentially could be done with `sortable`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help: [ReactWM](http://stayradiated.github.io/reactwm/)

It's in React though... Not sure about jQuery and jQuery UI.